# Cannot do a primary vote: errors

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, voting

Whenever I try to cast a vote on primary, I get a red popup saying:

```
An error has occurred - please retry your request.
```

I have already force-reloaded the site, but that did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got the same, but the votes still stuck.  I figured Evan was trying to grab some hanging chads hoping to force a mis-election.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bug with some localization code - a fix is going out right now.

Also, your vote was properly recorded; the bug only affected any optional display message that might have been sent back to the client.